# Why Django Count on M2M Field returns wrong value?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a manager that calculates all acquired skills by counting sessions related to educational materials attached to a specific skill. Here are my models and manager:

```
class Trajectory(CommonSystemObjectModel):
    actives = models.ManyToManyField(
        'actives.Active',
        verbose_name='Profile Goals',
        through='actives.TrajectoryActive',
        blank=True
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True,
        verbose_name='Is the profile currently active'
    )

class TrajectoryActive(CommonPriorityDataAbstractModel):
    trajectory = models.ForeignKey(
        to='trajectories.Trajectory',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Profile',
        related_name='trajectory_actives',
        db_index=True
    )
    active: Active = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Active,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Goal',
        related_name='active_trajectories',
        db_index=True
    )
    threats = models.ManyToManyField(
        to='threats.Threat',
        verbose_name='Skills',
        through='threats.ActiveThreat'
    )

class ActiveThreat(CommonPriorityDataAbstractModel):
    """Skill Model"""
    threat: Threat = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Threat,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        verbose_name='Skill',
        db_index=True,
        related_name='threat_actives'
    )
    trajectory_active = models.ForeignKey(
        to='actives.TrajectoryActive',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        db_index=True,
        verbose_name='Goal attached to the profile',
        related_name='active_threats'
    )
    content = models.ManyToManyField(
        CommonContentDataModel,
        verbose_name='Educational Materials attached to the skill',
        blank=True,
        db_index=True,
        related_name='content_threats'
    )

    objects = ActiveThreatManager()

class ActiveThreatManager(CommonObjectContentTypeManager):

    @staticmethod
    def _get_is_completed_case() -> Case:
        """A skill is considered acquired if the number of educational materials is greater than 0, the                    number of users is greater than 0, and the number of sessions on the skill's educational materials is greater than or equal to the number of users times the number of educational materials."""
        return Case(
            When(
                Q(users_count__gt=0) &
                Q(content_count__gt=0) &
                Q(content__isnull=False) &
                Q(completed_sessions_count__gte=F('users_count') * F('content_count')),
                then=True,
            ),
            default=False,
            output_field=models.BooleanField()
        )

    def default_metrics(self, is_completed: bool = None, **kwargs) -> QuerySet:
        """Obtain skill metrics for profile goal metric calculation"""
        qs = super().get_queryset().filter(**kwargs).annotate(
            content_count=Count('content', distinct=True), # even without disintct incorrect value
            completed_sessions_count=Count(
                'content__sessions',
                filter=Q(
                    content__sessions__completion_status=COMPLETED_KEY,
                    content__sessions__user=F('trajectory_active__trajectory__users'),
                    content__sessions__completion_datetime__isnull=False
                ),
                distinct=True
            ),
            users_count=Count('trajectory_active__trajectory__users', distinct=True)
        ).annotate(
            is_completed=self._get_is_completed_case()
        )
        return qs.filter(is_completed=is_completed) if is_completed else qs
```

```
# Each skill is annotated with the 'content_count' field
skill.content.add(content1, content2)
skill.content.count()  # returns 2 correct
skill = ActiveThreat.objects.default_metrics(pk=skill.pk).first()  # obtain the annotated metric
skill.content_count  # returns 1 incorrect
skill.content.count()  # still returns 2 still correct
```

The problem is that the content_count annotation is not providing the expected results. It returns incorrect values, and the count of related content remains the same. Why is this happening, and how can I solve it without using raw SQL?